# URL rewriting variable name

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite an URL so that a passed variable is replaced with a new id, for example;

`wwww.domain.com/default.php?s=1&lang=en`

To be rewritten to:

`www.domain.com/default.php?id=1$lang=en`

The s variable being replaced with id

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^s=(.+)$ id=$1 [R,NC,L]
```

also

```
RewriteRule ^s=(.+)$ id=%1 [R,NC,L]
```

no luck... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if even if you don't have `s` as the first variable. (Not sure what you really want.)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)*s=(.*)(&*)$
RewriteRule ^default.php$ default.php?%1&id=%2%3
```

Comment: Almost -- right now it's a way to broad as it will also match `/default.php?yes=123&lang=en`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
RewriteRule ^default.php?s=([0-9]+)&lang=en$ default.php?id=$1&lang=en
```

Edit.
A more generic version.

```
RewriteRule ([^?]+)?s=([0-9]+)&lang=([A-z]{2})$ $1?id=$2&lang=$3
```

Comment: RewriteRule does not work with query string like that -- only with help of RewriteCond. Therefore this rule is completely useless in Apache

Comment: LazyOne - I always use it in this way, I know it isn't the best way. It should work though, at least the first one should.

Comment: You see -- RewriteRule pattern only matches **path part** of the URL -- query string has to be matched via RewriteCond. I have NEVER seen it working in this way (unless you have some unknown-to-me-yet extra module installed/enabled that allows such behaviour). I was debugging quite a lot of rewrite rules (where Apache gives detailed info on what data it is working with right now) and I can clearly see that query string matching has to be done separately.